# How to prevent specific child element to be affected by href

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want when clicked on the child facebook do something else instead of href to the `a` tag, I want to do it with javascript also, It was not about to have them outside of it, I want to do it when it is still inside of it

```html
<a href="www.google.com">
  
  <h1>When you click, facebook will open</h1>
  <h1>When you click, facebook will open</h1>
  <h1>When you click, facebook will open</h1>
  <p>I don't want facebook</p>
  
</a>
```

Comment: faceb00k is equal to g00gle now.

Comment: @JovylleBermudez well they change it already you're prob sleeping when they did it. now you know :P :D..

Answer (score 1):

You can put it outside of your a tag then you can always put a separate a tag in each of the element where you want them to link. Let me know if this is what you mean.

```html
<h1><a href="www.facebook.com">When you click, facebook will open</a></h1>
  <h1><a href="www.facebook.com">When you click, facebook will open</a></h1>
  <h1><a href="www.facebook.com">When you click, facebook will open</a></h1>
  

  <p>I don't want facebook</p>
```

Comment: It was not about to have them outside of it, I want to do it when it is still inside of it, maybe javascript can work

Comment: what are you trying to do? why do you want to put an argument? in script if this is click windows.location.href ="this is your url" or "# ", I'm getting a little confuse of what you want. Your html is not right if you really put it that way. Let me know what do you want to attain.

Answer (score 0):

**Something like this?**

```html
<a href="www.google.com">
  
  <h1>When you click, facebook will open</h1>
  <h1>When you click, facebook will open</h1>
  <h1>When you click, facebook will open</h1>
</a>
<p>I don't want facebook</p>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).